# What to do when SVN Checkout stops working

Tags: svn, codeplex

Today, my SVN repository on CodePlex stopped working.

Trying to do a fresh checkout, I get the following error:

Command: Checkout from https://digger.svn.codeplex.com/svn, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Error: PROPFIND of '/svn': 207 Multi-Status (https://digger.svn.codeplex.com)

I've posted a support request on CodePlex, but other than that, are there steps to resolve this type of SVN error? (All Update and Commit operations also fail, but have been working fine for months before today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Codeplex team suggested that I convert over to Mercurial, as it was an unrecoverable bug with their SVN Bridge setup.  Instead, we just reset the entire repository and recommited everything.